# SED Command Not Working To Replace String in PHP files

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replaced a string in all php files with an empty string and it just seems to be ignoring it all together... No errors, yet nothing is replaced in the files.

could someone tell me what is wrong with this command?

`find ./ -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/session_save_path\('tcp\:\/\/redis\.domain\.com\:6379\?auth\=secret'\);/ /g' {} \;`

Comment: If you're using GNU sed, `\?` in a basic regular expression means 'match the previous thing 0 or 1 times', not a literal question mark. (This is a GNU extension to normal BRE syntax)

Comment: And `\( \)` is a capturing group; not sure if that's intentional or you want to match literal parens.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```sh
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i "s/session_save_path('tcp:\/\/redis.domain.com:6379?auth=secret')//g" {} \;
```

You need not escape braces in sed, because sed uses BRE regex.

Instead of using `/` as delimiter, one can use any character except `\`

```sh
# Using # as delimiter for the sed command
# / after tcp need not be escaped as it isn't the delimiter

find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i "s#session_save_path('tcp://redis.domain.com:6379?auth=secret')##g" {} \;
```

Learn more about BRE, ERE regex [here](https://learnbyexample.github.io/gnu-bre-ere-cheatsheet/)